# How do I compare scores on two different scales but one group?

Tags: correlation, spss

My hypothesis is: "Women who score high on self-esteem will score low on upward comparison." I have all the data cleaned up and the total scores found for all my scales, I am just unsure what to do from there.

Answer (score 2):

Your study question isn't about whether the scores on one variable are higher or lower than scores on another variable (they are incommensurate).  Rather, your hypothesis is about an *association* between those two variables.  You can assess that, and test it, by computing the correlation between the variables.

If you are concerned about the typical assumptions of Pearson's product-moment correlation, you could use a non-parametric correlation, such as Spearman's.

Comment: @Brendan, I can't understand that hypothesis.